# Creating heatmap from vector tiles using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, heat-map, vector-tiles

I know that is possible to make a heatmap using [ol/layer/Heatmap](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Heatmap-Heatmap.html), but this component accept as source only ol/source/Vector component.

Someone have build a heatmap using VectorTile as source? Can you suggest me a workaround?

Comment: A workaround is to load the tiles into a normal vector layer using a tile strategy and a custom loader similar to loading MVT tiles in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-custom-mvt.html   It would be simpler to implement if the tile strategy uses a single zoom level of the tile grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Mike proposed, to load vector tile features into normal vector heatmap layer is probably the only solution. Problem is that with vector tiles number of features can change greatly with zoom change, so with zoom change previous features in normal vector layer have to be cleared and new ones added.

One possible solution for this would be to use vector tile source method `getFeaturesInExtent` after all tiles are loaded, to get all features in visible extent and select the ones to be added to the heatmap vector layer. Vector tile features/geometries cannot be used directly, since they have different structure that normal vector features. Features for normal vector layer have to be created from coordinates of vector features.

Code below is more a proof of concept than bulletproof solution. Whole idea is to wait for map `moveend` events and vector tile layer `postrender` events. When `moveend` is detected, set a flag, and when a `postrender` event is detected and `moveend` flag is set, do inventory of vector tile layer features with the `getFeaturesInExtent` method, clear heatmap vector layer source and add desired features (points) from vector tile layer inventory.

Code uses ArcGIS World_Basemap_v2 vector tile layer as a source. For heatmap points cities are filtered in. Since cities in the layer have no property to be used as weight, each city gets the same value `0.8`.

```
var defaultStyles = new ol.layer.Vector().getStyleFunction()();

var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  if (feature.get('layer') == 'Coastline') {
    return(defaultStyles);
  }
};

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.MVT(),
    url: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
    wrapX: false
  }),
  style: styleFunction
});

var heatmapSource = new ol.source.Vector();

var heatmapLayer = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
  source: heatmapSource,
  weight: function(feature) {
    return(0.8);
  }
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    extent: vectorLayer.getSource().getTileGrid().getExtent()
  }),
  layers: [vectorLayer, heatmapLayer]
});
  
var moveEnd = false;
var firstTime = true;
map.on('moveend', function() {
  moveEnd = true;
  if (firstTime) {
    firstTime = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      refreshHeatmap();
    }, 250);
  }
});

vectorLayer.on('postrender', function(evt) {
  if (moveEnd) {
    moveEnd = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      refreshHeatmap();
    }, 0);
  }  
});

function refreshHeatmap() {
  var geometry, extent, source, features;
  source = vectorLayer.getSource();
  features = source.getFeaturesInExtent(map.getView().calculateExtent());
  heatmapSource.clear();
  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    geometry = features[i].getGeometry();
    if ((geometry.getType() == 'Point') && (features[i].get('layer').substring(0, 4) == 'City')  && features[i].get('_name_en') )  {
      extent = geometry.getExtent();
      heatmapSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.Point([extent[0], extent[1]])}));
    }
  }
}
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/y1xus3m0/ and two screenshots at different zooms:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can get vector tile features with standard geometries by specifying `new ol.format.MVT({featureClass: ol.Feature})`

Comment: @Mike If I want to use some features (points) for heatmap and some features (polygons) for actual display in vector tile layer (as in the above example), would this be OK for vector tile layer features?

Comment: It would work https://jsfiddle.net/hmtofbrw/   The rendering of the vector tiles might be less efficient with standard features, but the cities could be used directly in the heatmap

Comment: @Mike Good to know, thanks!